# is there a way to instead of making double not freeze project and instead say invalid number?

Tags: c#, math, double

i am new in stack overflow, but i've ran into a problem.
what i want to do exactly is an advanced calculator, but can't find out a way to give an error message (then i will add a retry option) instead of making the console freeze.

```
            Console.Write("Type A Number: ");
            double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            //detects numbers
            if (num1 != "1")
                Console.WriteLine("invalid number!");
            //detects numbers

            Console.Write("Type An Operator: ");
            string op = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Type Another Number: ");
            double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            //the operator logic system!!!
```

the operator logic system detects if the operator (+ - x/* / etc) is valid, but I can't find out for number. after that, I am going to make a game, but I can't find out for this one now.

Comment: your program freezes? Are you sure it doesn´t produce a `FormatException`?

Comment: _if (num1 != "1")_ You compare a double with a string. Not very usefull. Also, use the `double.TryParse()` to avoid exceptions.

Comment: This code must through a compilation error as you cannot compare double with string as you did in if(num1 != "1")

Comment: it does produce formatexception, but i want it to do invalid number and then restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Console.Write("Type A Number: ");

if (!double.TryParse (Console.ReadLine(), out double num1))
     Console.WriteLine("invalid number!");
```

`TryParse` returns false if the entered text is not a valid `double`. If it is valid it returns true and puts the number into `num1`.

Comment: for a reason even if i put a number it says invalid number, but it still calculates.

Comment: oh i found out the issue, i will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This code is going to cause you issues if the user enters an unexpected value.  E.g.  They enter a string instead of a number.  So you need to also look for and account for that.

Best is to create different methods which will check the input and only return a valid result, otherwise to prompt the user.  So you have something like this;

The main method calls submethods, so is relatively simple.
You call `GetValidNumber` to return the number inputs for bother number 1 and number 2
`GetValidOperator` to return the valid operator, which itself calls `IsValidOperator` to check the input is valid (as there is more to check).

Double.TryParse(...) is the main check if the double number entered is valid or not.  But using TryParese it will not through an exception if the user enters an non-valid number, but rather just return false.  So it is a safe way of checking user input in this case.

The code might need refining and error checking improved, but it should put you on the right course.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
      double number1 = GetValidNumber("Enter first number");
      string op = GetValidOperator();
      double number2 = GetValidNumber("Enter second number");
      Console.WriteLine($"Operation is  {number1} {op} {number2}");
     //Add code to perform your operation
}


private static double GetValidNumber(string message)
{
      Console.WriteLine(message);
      string input = Console.ReadLine();
      double output;
      while (!Double.TryParse(input, out output) )
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Invalid number!  Please try again");
          input = Console.ReadLine();
      }
      return output;
  }

  private static string GetValidOperator()
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Enter an operator + - * / ");
      string input = Console.ReadLine();
      while (!IsValidOperator(input))
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Invalid Operator!  Please try again");
          input = Console.ReadLine();
      }
      return input;
  }

  private static bool IsValidOperator(string input)
  {
      bool result = false;
      if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
          return false;
      if (input.Length != 1)
          return false;
      if (input[0] == '+' || input[0] == '-' || input[0] == '/' || input[0] == '*')
          return true;
       else
          return result;
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

Well, you can use Double.Parse instead of Convert.ToDouble. It will throw exception on failed conversion and you will be able to handle that.

Comment: Both throw an exception.

Comment: `Convert` also throws.